# pushd in vbscript not working

Tags: vbscript

I am writing a vbscript that needs to `pushd` onto a shared server location, execute some commands and finally `popd`.

`\\sharedLocation\server` is a valid shared folder location to the server.

**script.vbs**

```
set ws = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
arg = Wscript.Arguments.Named("arg")
push = "C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /c pushd " & arg
ws.Run(push)
```

I execute the above script in command prompt using

```
> script.vbs /arg:\\sharedLocation\Server
```

but nothing happens. What could possibly go wrong here? I am running this script on Windows XP.

Answer (score 1):

`pushd` is actually working, but you used `cmd` with /c switch, witch causes `cmd` to run `pushd` and exit immediately. If you want `cmd` to stay open, you should use /k switch.